# layout_below with @id not working but with @+id work

Tags: android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="20dp">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/content">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/idcontentline"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center|top"
android:src="@drawable/line"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/idcontentline"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/idcontenttext"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="this is a sample" />

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i use android:layout_below="@+id/idcontentline",everything is correct and textview is below of imageview.But when use @id instead of @+id,it's not work.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the project several times, just it.

Answer (score 3):

> The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the string indicates that the XML parser should parse and expand the rest of the ID string and identify it as an ID resource. The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file). There are a number of other ID resources that are offered by the Android framework. When referencing an Android resource ID, you do not need the plus-symbol, but must add the android package namespace.

Comment: Exactly.question is here.when we want to declare a new id,must use plus,and when want to use it,must @id.but in my question it's not work.

Comment: Clean Build your project than new reference id is generated than it may work properly